# How can I rewrite this query without repeating SELECT subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, query-optimization

I have written a query like this.  It is working and giving me the result which I wanted.
I have a `SELECT` query to get `CAR_AMOUNT` and `HOTEL_AMOUNT`.
But, I have to repeat the same `SELECT` query to get the `SUM` of both. I am not able to use alias name. How can I avoid this?

```
SELECT B.EMPLOYEE_ID,
       (select SUM(AMOUNT) 
         FROM travel_reimbursements_items
         WHERE type = 'CAR' 
         AND travel_request_no = B.travel_request_no 
        AND STATUS='APPROVED') as CAR_AMOUNT,
       (select SUM(AMOUNT)
        FROM travel_reimbursements_items 
        WHERE type = 'HOTEL' 
        AND travel_request_no = B.travel_request_no 
        AND STATUS='APPROVED') as HOTEL_AMOUNT,
       NVL((select SUM(AMOUNT) 
            FROM travel_reimbursements_items 
            WHERE type = 'CAR' 
            AND travel_request_no = B.travel_request_no 
            AND STATUS='APPROVED'),0)
        +NVL((select SUM(AMOUNT) 
            FROM travel_reimbursements_items
            WHERE type = 'HOTEL' 
            AND travel_request_no = B.travel_request_no 
            AND STATUS='APPROVED'),0) as TOTAL
FROM TRAVEL_REQUEST_ITEM A
     LEFT OUTER JOIN TRAVEL_REQUEST B 
       ON (B.TRAVEL_REQUEST_NO= A.TRAVEL_REQUEST_SR_NO)
```

Comment: Which flavour of SQL? SQL Server, Oracle ... ?

Comment: Im sorry ...forgot to mention it.. its Oracle  ....

Comment: Why don't you make the sum on the application level, I hope is possible in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work in oracle.

```
SELECT B.EMPLOYEE_ID,
           SUM(CASE WHEN C.type = 'CAR' and C.STATUS='APPROVED' THEN C.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) as CAR_AMOUNT,
           SUM(CASE WHEN C.type = 'HOTEL' and C.STATUS='APPROVED' THEN C.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) as HOTEL_AMOUNT,
           SUM(CASE WHEN C.type IN ('CAR', 'HOTEL') and C.STATUS='APPROVED' THEN C.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) as TOTAL
FROM TRAVEL_REQUEST_ITEM A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TRAVEL_REQUEST B ON (B.TRAVEL_REQUEST_NO= A.TRAVEL_REQUEST_SR_NO)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TRAVEL_REIMBURSEMENTS_ITEMS C ON (C.TRAVEL_REQUEST_NO = A.TRAVEL_REQUEST_SR_NO) 
GROUP BY B.EMPLOYEE_ID
```

Just do a conditional sum based on the item type.

Comment: this will not work for me as i want to add few more columns with different select queries

Comment: What columns? This meets your requirement in your question and can be extended as needed. If you want something more you need to post your table structure and explain what you are trying to do. The concept of joining the tables and then summing based on conditions is sound - what can't you adapt from the answer to your requirements?

Comment: SUM(CASE WHEN C.type = 'CAR' and C.STATUS='APPROVED' THEN C.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) as CAR_AMOUNT,            
SUM(CASE WHEN C.type = 'HOTEL' and C.STATUS='APPROVED' THEN C.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) as HOTEL_AMOUNT, 
SUM(CASE WHEN C.STATUS='APPROVED' THEN C.PHONE ELSE 0 END) as PHONE_AMNT,

Comment: want to add few more amount like PHONE_AMOUNT in the prev query and it should also come under total... I am not able to figure it out...I was looking if we can use the alias name to calculate the total

Comment: Do you have to have these amounts in separate columns? It might make more sense just to group by the TYPE column...

Comment: Ok. So you have a record of type "PHONE" on the items table? Just add another column to the query: `SUM(CASE WHEN C.type = 'PHONE' and C.STATUS='APPROVED' THEN C.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) as PHONE_AMOUNT` You can do the same for any other "type".

Comment: Also, I would suggest doing it like in Rob van Wijk's answer - put the shared criteria in the ON clause of your join to the items table, and the specific criteria in each SUM column.

Comment: SUM(CASE WHEN C.STATUS='APPROVED' THEN C.PHONE ELSE 0 END) as PHONE_AMNT... i am not fethcing AMOUNT...BUt column PHONE....so how will i add PHONE_AMOUNT to my TOTAL?

Comment: Are you only pulling the PHONE column for CAR/HOTEL types, or all?

Comment: If it's just CAR/HOTEL types, then just add the column to your total: `SUM(CASE WHEN C.type IN ('CAR', 'HOTEL') and C.STATUS='APPROVED' THEN C.AMOUNT + C.PHONE ELSE 0 END) as TOTAL`.

Comment: If its any type, do the addition outside the CASE statement: `SUM(CASE WHEN C.type IN ('CAR', 'HOTEL') and C.STATUS='APPROVED' THEN C.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN C.STATUS='APPROVED' THEN C.PHONE ELSE 0 END) as TOTAL'`

Answer (score 6):

```
select b.employee_id
     , sum(case when c.type = 'CAR' then c.amount end) car_amount
     , sum(case when c.type = 'HOTEL' then c.amount end) hotel_amount
     , sum(c.amount) total
  from travel_request_item a
       left outer join travel_request b
         on (b.travel_request_no= a.travel_request_sr_no)
       left outer join travel_reimbursements_items c
         on (   c.travel_request_no = b.travel_request_no
            and c.type in ('CAR','HOTEL')
            and c.status = 'APPROVED'
            )
 group by b.employee_id
```

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: +1 I like putting the shared criteria in the JOIN instead of the CASE statements.

Comment: this will not work for me as i want to add few more columns with different select queries...

Comment: See N West's great comment starting with "What columns?".